# Parse the string 'name' from the input_url extracted from the url 'path'

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Hello I am trying to parse the name "beer.master.121" from the input_url by using regex, and I am looking for a better Regex than the one I have

Actually my function and results are the following:

```
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlsplit


input_url = 'https://www.pizza.com/beer.master.121/margaretha/98799csduu99003/'

def get_url_data(input_url):
    
    url_parts = urlsplit(input_url)
    query = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(url_parts.query))
    path_ = url_parts.path
    
    if 'margaretha/' in input_url:
        publisher = re.search('\w+(?=\s*/[^/])', path_).group(0)
        print(publisher)
        return publisher
```

When I run the code, I get only the last word:

```
get_url_data(input_url)
'121'
```

Desired outputs:

```
input_url = 'https://www.pizza.com/beer.master.121/margaretha/98799csduu99003/'
get_url_data(input_url)
'beer.master.121'

input_url = 'https://www.pizza.com/beer.master/margaretha/98799csduuppP000/'
get_url_data(input_url)
'beer.master'

input_url = 'https://www.pizza.com/beer/margaretha/98799csduuppP000/'
get_url_data(input_url)
'beer'

input_url = 'https://www.pizza.com/lovely/10022648/margaretha/939520'
get_url_data(input_url)
'10022648'

input_url = 'https://www.pizza.com/lovely/jhonson.1002278/margaretha/939520'
get_url_data(input_url)
'jhonson.1002278'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def get_url_data(input_url):
    path = urlsplit(input_url).path
    try:
        idx = path.index('margaretha')
    except:
        return None
    return path[:idx - 1].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method with other info.

##### Output

```
url: https://www.pizza.com/beer.master.121/margaretha/98799csduu99003/
network location: www.pizza.com
directories: ['beer.master.121', 'margaretha', '98799csduu99003']
target: beer.master.121

url: https://www.pizza.com/beer.master/margaretha/98799csduuppP000/
network location: www.pizza.com
directories: ['beer.master', 'margaretha', '98799csduuppP000']
target: beer.master

url: https://www.pizza.com/beer/margaretha/98799csduuppP000/
network location: www.pizza.com
directories: ['beer', 'margaretha', '98799csduuppP000']
target: beer

url: https://www.pizza.com/lovely/10022648/margaretha/939520
network location: www.pizza.com
directories: ['lovely', '10022648', 'margaretha', '939520']
target: 10022648

url: https://www.pizza.com/lovely/jhonson.1002278/margaretha/939520
network location: www.pizza.com
directories: ['lovely', 'jhonson.1002278', 'margaretha', '939520']
target: jhonson.1002278
```

##### Code

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse


urls = [
    'https://www.pizza.com/beer.master.121/margaretha/98799csduu99003/',
    'https://www.pizza.com/beer.master/margaretha/98799csduuppP000/',
    'https://www.pizza.com/beer/margaretha/98799csduuppP000/',
    'https://www.pizza.com/lovely/10022648/margaretha/939520',
    'https://www.pizza.com/lovely/jhonson.1002278/margaretha/939520'
]

for url in urls:
    print()
    print(f'url: {url}')

    parts = urlparse(url)
    print(f'network location: {parts.netloc}')

    directories = parts.path.strip('/').split('/')
    print(f'directories: {directories}')

    margaretha_index = directories.index('margaretha')
    ret = directories[margaretha_index-1]
    print(f'target: {ret}')
```

```
def get_url_data(url):
    parts = urlparse(url)
    directories = parts.path.strip('/').split('/')
    margaretha_index = directories.index('margaretha')
    return directories[margaretha_index-1]
```

##### Reference

https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-parse-url-structures-using-python